# Is it possible to call a function without a direct reference in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

*beginner here*

I am trying to make a "logger" for my c++ learning project, I´ve already set up code to manage the logging itself, but I can´t get the function to work from other classes.

Here´s my "Debugger" class

```
class MSEdebug
    {

        MSEdebug(){logOutput.open("log.txt");}

        ~MSEdebug() { logOutput.close(); }

        void debuglog(std::string info)
        {
#ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << "LOG:" << info << std::endl;
#endif // DEBUG
            logOutput << "LOG:" << info << "\n";
        }

        std::ofstream logOutput;


    };
```

And here´s what I want to be able to do:

```
#include "MSE_debug.h"

//...

MSEapp::debugTest()
{

     MSEdebug::debuglog("Test, 1, 2, 3...");

}
```

Now this doesn´t work, and you experienced C++ programmers are probably rolling your eyes already, but could you be so kind to tell me how I would get it to work.

*Btw, I hope I´ve done this correctly, this is my first question, so I´m sorry if it´s bad*

Comment: Looks like you need to use a static function.

Comment: `debuglog` is a method of the `MSEdebug` class, so you need an actual variable of type `MSEdebug` to call it on.

Comment: Member functions of a `class` are by default private. You should make `debuglog` public.

Comment: @NateEldredge thank you very much for that answer. I think i might "misformulated" my question, this is exactly what I mean, I don´t want to create a variable of type MSEdebug in *every single* class I want to use it in, so I was wondering if it were possible to do without the variable. I´ll change the question to better suit what I´m actually asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical way is to use the singleton pattern to have a unique instance of the class `MSEDebug` that is easily accessible.

```
class MSEdebug
    {

        MSEdebug(){logOutput.open("log.txt");}
    public:
        ~MSEdebug() { logOutput.close(); }

        void debuglog(std::string info)
        {
#ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << "LOG:" << info << std::endl;
#endif // DEBUG
            logOutput << "LOG:" << info << "\n";
        }
        static MSEdebug& getInstance() {
            static MSEdebug instance;

            return instance;
        }
    private:
        std::ofstream logOutput;
    };
```

You can then use it that way:

```
     MSEdebug::getInstance().debuglog("Test, 1, 2, 3...");
```

Comment: Rather complicated and certainly roundabout way of doing a simple thing.  Useful for a complex class that has several methods.

Comment: The use of `new MSEdebug()` is not mandatory for a singleton. A static instance is sufficient and will also get cleaned up when the C++ runtime stops.

Comment: Thanks very much, I wasn´t expecting so many people to reply so quickly, you guys are breathtaking

Comment: Well known patterns have a nice property: they are documented and have been intensively tested. There are tons are variations over the singleton pattern in C++. They work well *almost* always, but can fail in some corner cases. Whenever I can, I stick to *best practices* and *well known patterns* in order no to later be caught by a corner case. Being an old dinosaur I have experimented a lot of traps, and now try hard to keep away from them...

Comment: I'm trying to say that there is currently no way for your d'tor to be called.

Comment: @quamrana: Oops. You are right. This is *the corner case* I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Does that mean you'll vote for my answer? But, of course, after you've fixed the other problem with yours.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `std::cout` is basically a singleton (although you can instantiate other `std::ostream` instances)

Answer (score 4):

This might be the one case where a singleton might be in order:

```cpp
class MSEdebug {
private:
    MSEdebug(){ logOutput.open("log.txt"); }

    ~MSEdebug() { logOutput.close(); }
public:
    static MSEdebug& instance(){
        static MSEdebug debug;
        return debug;
    }
    void debuglog(std::string info) {
#ifdef DEBUG
        std::cout << "LOG:" << info << '\n';
#endif // DEBUG
        logOutput << "LOG:" << info << '\n';
        }
private:
    std::ofstream logOutput;
};
```

Usage like this:

```cpp
#include "MSE_debug.h"

//...

MSEapp::debugTest()
{
     MSEdebug::instance().debuglog("Test, 1, 2, 3...");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  You need to use a static function.  Here is some code to get you started.

```
class MSEdebug
    {
public:
        MSEdebug(){}

        ~MSEdebug() { logOutput.close(); }

        static void debuglog(std::string info)
        {
#ifdef DEBUG
            std::cout << "LOG:" << info << std::endl;
#endif // DEBUG
            if( ! logOutput.is_open() )
            { 
               //first use - open logfile
               logOutput.open("log.txt");
            }
            logOutput << "LOG:" << info << "\n";
        }

        static std::ofstream logOutput;


    };
```

You will have to construct logOutput somewhere in a .cpp file

```
std::ofstream MSEdebug::logOutput;
```

BTW someone suggested "you need an actual variable of type MSEdebug".  This is wrong.  If you do it that way, each time you construct an "actual variable" the class will try to open another copy of the log file.

Comment: You can make it `inline` and initialize if in the class definition. Assuming use of c++17.

Comment: Constructor and destructor like these are dangerous for static member. I suggest you remove them.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen True.  However this code should make a workable first version.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux  Correct.  I have fixed the code in my answer.

Comment: @ravenspoint, ye sorry, thank you very much for your help, you guys are godsend

Comment: What is the idea behind the c'tor and d'tor of your `MSEdebug` class?